# failed to install greenplum command center when running gpccinstall

Tags: greenplum

I downloaded greenplum-cc-web-4.6.1-LINUX-x86_64.zip for my greenplum db with 5.18, and followed this link (https://gpcc.docs.pivotal.io/460/topics/setup-collection-agents.html) to install command center. Everything is OK while there is a failure about gpccinstall. It showed following errors:

```
RunCommandOnEachHost fail on host:  client-gp03.bj
Error when unzip remote binary on sdw3 bin/gpccws
bin/ccagent
bin/gpcc
conf/app.conf
gpcc_path.sh
bin/start_agent.sh
bin/queryinfocat.sh
bin/gpcc_md5
ccdata/
alert-email/alertTemplate.html
alert-email/send_alert.sh.sample
languages/
languages/zh.json
languages/en.json

Error when unzip remote binary on client-gp00.bj bin/gpccws
bin/ccagent
bin/gpcc
conf/app.conf
gpcc_path.sh
bin/start_agent.sh
bin/queryinfocat.sh
bin/gpcc_md5
ccdata/
alert-email/alertTemplate.html
alert-email/send_alert.sh.sample
languages/
languages/zh.json
languages/en.json

Error when unzip remote binary on client-gp01.bj bin/gpccws
bin/ccagent
bin/gpcc
conf/app.conf
gpcc_path.sh
bin/start_agent.sh
bin/queryinfocat.sh
bin/gpcc_md5
ccdata/
alert-email/alertTemplate.html
alert-email/send_alert.sh.sample
languages/
languages/zh.json
languages/en.json

Error when unzip remote binary on client-gp02.bj bin/gpccws
bin/ccagent
bin/gpcc
conf/app.conf
gpcc_path.sh
bin/start_agent.sh
bin/queryinfocat.sh
bin/gpcc_md5
ccdata/
alert-email/alertTemplate.html
alert-email/send_alert.sh.sample
languages/
languages/zh.json
languages/en.json

Error when unzip remote binary on client-gp03.bj Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'client-gp03.bj' differs from the key for the IP address '10.136.173.8'
Offending key for IP in /home/gpadmin/.ssh/known_hosts:10
Matching host key in /home/gpadmin/.ssh/known_hosts:17
tar: bin/gpccws: Cannot open: File exists
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors

RunCommandOnEachHost failure happened
```

Can anyone encounter this issue before? I did some search in google and pivotal community, but failed to find some solution. Any help is appreciated.

BTW, when I ignored above errors, and continued, I found the gpcc web server can be started successfully. And when I logged in, only "Query Monitor" UI section show one warning: "GPCC is no longer receiving updates. Check your network status or gpcc status and refresh this page.", other part of UI seems OK.

Answer (score 1):

From here:

```
Error when unzip remote binary on client-gp03.bj Warning: the ECDSA host key for 'client-gp03.bj' differs from the key for the IP address '10.136.173.8'
Offending key for IP in /home/gpadmin/.ssh/known_hosts:10
Matching host key in /home/gpadmin/.ssh/known_hosts:17
tar: bin/gpccws: Cannot open: File exists
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

You have duplicate ssh fingerprint keys in your `/home/gpadmin/.ssh/known_hosts` file. I recommend removing both lines 10 and 17 from that file, then running `ssh-keyscan client-gp03.bj >> /home/gpadmin/.ssh/known_hosts`

After this is complete, try ssh-ing to the host, to see that the fingerprint error is cleared up, and if so, try the gpcc installation again.

Comment: Thx。 While I followed your advice, and reinstall it to a new folder, it throws following errors:
Read setup up config from  conf/gpcc.conf  ****
RunCommandOnEachHost fail on host:  sdw3  ****
Error when remove remote binary on client-gp02.bj   ****
Error when remove remote binary on client-gp01.bj   ****
Error when remove remote binary on sdw3 rm: cannot remove ‘/tmp/gpcc.tar.gz’: No such file or directory  ****

Error when remove remote binary on client-gp03.bj  ****
Error when remove remote binary on client-gp00.bj  ****
RunCommandOnEachHost failure happened ****

Comment: Sorry that I don't know how to format above comment, so I use **** to replace carriage. Here sdw3 is the segment installed on client-gp03.bj. There was no further detail error info in installation log file

Comment: Without fixing above errors, I can start the web server successfully using "gpcc start".  With chrome development tool, I can find one "404 Not Found" error for uri: /gpcc_v1/gp_wlm/config in "Query Monitor" page, which displays text:GPCC is no longer receiving updates. Check your network status or gpcc status and refresh this page.  Not sure whether it was caused by above failure in install.

Comment: Thanks a lot. May you please take another look? @Tyler Ramer

Comment: I also found some error log in MASTER directory: 
2019-09-17 11:16:34|:-WARNING: [gpmmon.c:498] error 104 from recvpkt system call ****
2019-09-17 11:16:34|:-WARNING: [gpmmon.c:698] cannot connect to client-gp03.bj (W.X.Y.Z:P) ****
2019-09-17 11:16:42|:-LOG: Connection to sdw3 lost.  Restarting gpsmon. ****
2019-09-17 11:16:50|:-WARNING: [gpmmon.c:498] error 104 from recvpkt system call ****
2019-09-17 11:16:50|:-WARNING: [gpmmon.c:698] cannot connect to sdw3 (W.X.Y.Z:P) ****
2019-09-17 11:16:58|:-LOG: Connection to sdw3 lost.  Restarting gpsmon. ****

Comment: But I'm sure I had put gpmon with ip W.X.Y.Z into pg_hba.conf